# Conky wrong alignment at startup in Debian under VMware

Tags: debian, vmware, conky

When I start my Debian running inside a VMWare, the screen resolution for the login is a small square, like 800x600.
After the login, the screen goes full 1680x1050.

The result: Conky is ALWAYS opening in the wrong place (somewhere in the middle of the screen).

The thing is, after the screen is full size, if I edit the .conkyrc config file (add and remove a white space) and save it, Conky reopen in the correct place of the screen.

What I have already tried:

- Delay Conky startup in the Conky call
- Delay Conky startup in the script that calls Conky
- The combination of above options.

Here is the main part of the config file:

```
background yes
use_xft yes
xftfont 123:size=8
xftalpha 0.1
update_interval 3
total_run_times 0
own_window yes
own_window_type normal 
own_window_transparent yes
own_window_argb_visual yes
own_window_hints undecorated,below,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager
double_buffer yes
minimum_size 250 5
maximum_width 400
draw_shades no
draw_outline no
draw_borders no
draw_graph_borders no
default_color gray
default_shade_color red
default_outline_color green
alignment top_right
gap_x 10
gap_y 10
no_buffers no
uppercase no
cpu_avg_samples 2
net_avg_samples 1
override_utf8_locale yes
use_spacer yes
text_buffer_size 256
position top right
```

Is there a way to solve that problem? Either making the login screen full size instead of 800x600 or some exotic Conky configuration tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer to this was to create a launcher on my desktop that runs the command `killall -HUP conky`, which triggers a conky reset and redraw when I double-click it.  I suppose I have not scripted it to run automatically because I usually lock screen instead of log out, and haven't rebooted the machine for months now.

No reason it can't be automated, though.  Something like this:  Make a file `~/conky-redraw` containing:

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 30
killall -HUP conky
```

Make it executable (`chmod 755 ~/conky-redraw`) and add it to your startup (however you usually do it, or add the line `~/conky-redraw &` to the end of `~./profile` for example).

Tweak the number of `sleep` seconds based on how long your desktop and conky take to get started and established.

Comment: It worked! Thank you! Since I'm using the latest debian, I had to create a conky-redraw.desktop at .config/autostart.